# Firefox execCommand doesn't require preventDefault

Tags: javascript, firefox, input, textarea, execcommand

The behaviour of execCommand `insertText` in Firefox does not require `e.preventDefault()` - however in chrome & other browsers this is required. How do I align this behaviour between browsers, without using navigator.

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/ArranGravestock/pen/BGVEJR)

```
function onPaste(e) {

  e.preventDefault() //required in chrome but not firefox?

  document.execCommand( "insertText", false, 'test' );
}
```

Comment: Does it make anything different, if you prevented the default in FF?

Comment: @Teemu If you prevent default in FF it will stop all action entirely, so it will not insertText. If you remove this it will fix the behaviour but in other browsers the default paste action will not be prevented and insert your original paste as well as the 'insertText' (e.g. 'test')

Comment: OK. Now, if I run `document.queryCommandEnabled('insertText')` in my FF63, I get `false`, meaning the command is not enabled (works fine in Chrome, though). When this is the case, you can't rely the command being enabled in any of your users' browser if they're using FF.

Comment: @Teemu `document.queryCommandEnabled('insertText')` returns false in both chrome and firefox for me